# Use Inconsolata font in emacs (centos)

Tags: emacs, fonts, centos

I have read through tons of questions about setting up the fonts in emacs but I have not been able to get it to work so far. Is there a step by step guide for changing the emacs default font to this (including font installation directions?) This is over ssh so I can't use a solution that involves the gui version of emacs.

Comment: If it's over SSH and you're using the console version of Emacs, the fonts will need to be installed on your *local* system, and set up for whatever terminal or SSH client you are using. Emacs has nothing to do with it.

Comment: ah.......... want to put that as the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is over ssh so I can't use a solution that involves the gui version of emacs.

Since you are connecting over SSH and using the terminal version of Emacs, you'll have to set up Inconsolata on your *local* machine, and configure your terminal or SSH client to use that font.

Emacs in the terminal has no concept of fonts; it simply uses whatever fonts the containing terminal uses.